# Convert template parameter into comma-separated list of template parameters

Tags: c++17, eigen3

Apologies if the title is misleading or if this question has been answered before.

I'm working with Eigen's Tensor module, particularly the `Eigen::TensorFixedSize` class as I know the shape at compile time.

Essentially, because this is a Lorentz problem, a rank-2 tensor would go like,

`Eigen::TensorFixedSize<double, Eigen::Sizes<4,4>> t;`

a rank-3 tensor,

`Eigen::TensorFixedSize<double, Eigen::Sizes<4,4,4>> t;`

and so on.

I'd like to write a class that is able to initialise a tensor depending on the rank. In pseudo-code,

```
template<typename RANK>
 class Foo
 {
  public:
   ...
  private:
   Eigen::TensorFixedSize<double, Eigen::Sizes<4,4,4,...,RANK times>> _t;
 }
```

somehow converting the template parameter from

`<2> --> <4,4>`

`<3> --> <4,4,4>`

up to an arbitrary unsigned int in `<N>`.

Would this be possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup.

```
template <class RankIdx>
struct TensorForRank;

template <std::size_t... RankIdx>
struct TensorForRank<std::index_sequence<RankIdx...>> {
    using type = Eigen::TensorFixedSize<double, Eigen::Sizes<(void(RankIdx), 4)...>>;
};

template <std::size_t Rank>
using TensorForRank_t = typename TensorForRank<std::make_index_sequence<Rank>>::type;
```

Use as:

```
template<std::size_t Rank>
class Foo
{
    // ...
private:
    TensorForRank_t<Rank> _t;
};
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jpNpfasTjtN6WeXD) (with a placeholder `test<...>` template as Eigen is not available)

Answer (score 1):

[Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55281376/27678) is very good, and what I'd go with.

The only downside is the "useless" generation of an index sequence [0, 1, 2, ...] whose values we ignore, and substitute for our own.

If we want to directly create the repeated values, we can write our own generator code (which is quite a bit more verbose):

Start with creating a type that can hold a number of `std::size_t` values by aliasing a [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence):

```
template<std::size_t... vals>
using value_sequence = std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, vals...>;
```

The goal is to ultimately create a `value_sequence<4, 4, 4>` and then instantiate an `Eigen::Sizes` using those 4s.

The next thing we need to be able to do is concatenate two sequences, because we're going to build it up like so:

```
concat(value_sequence<4>, value_sequence<4>) --> value_sequence<4, 4>
```

We can do this via a stub method that accepts two `value_sequence` types and returns the concatenated result. Note that we do not ever write a definition for this method; we're simply taking advantage of the type system to write less code than a template specialization would take:

```
template<std::size_t... lhs, std::size_t... rhs>
constexpr auto concat(value_sequence<lhs...>, value_sequence<rhs...>) -> value_sequence<lhs..., rhs...>;
```

At this point we have enough machinery to create a `value_sequence<4,4,4>`, so now we need a way to indicate the value we wish to use (4) and the number of times to repeat it (3) to produce it:

```
template<std::size_t value, std::size_t num_repeats>
struct repeated_value
{
    using left_sequence = value_sequence<value>;
    using right_sequence = typename repeated_value<value, num_repeats-1>::type;
    using type = decltype(concat(left_sequence{}, right_sequence{}));
};
```

`repeated_value<4, 3>::type` produces a `value_sequence<4, 4, 4>`.

Since `repeated_value<...>::type` is recursive, we need to provide a base case via partial specialization:

```
template<std::size_t value>
struct repeated_value<value, 1>
{
    using type = value_sequence<value>;
};
```

Great. All that's left is for us to receive an `Eigen::Sizes` class and a `value_sequence<4, 4, 4>` type, and produce `Eigen::Sizes<4, 4, 4>`.

We can do this with partial template specialization again:

```
template<template<std::size_t...> class T, class...>
struct InstantiateWithRepeatedVals;

template<template<std::size_t...> class T, std::size_t... vals>
struct InstantiateWithRepeatedVals<T, value_sequence<vals...>> 
{
    using type = T<vals...>;
};
```

That it! Throw in a few helpers to make using it easier, and we're done:

```
template<std::size_t value, std::size_t num_repeats>
using repeated_value_t = typename repeated_value<value, num_repeats>::type;

template<template<std::size_t...> class T, std::size_t Value, std::size_t N>
using InstantiateWithRepeatedVals_t = typename InstantiateWithRepeatedVals<T, repeated_value_t<Value, N>>::type;
```

Now we can use it like so:

```
using my_type = InstantiateWithRepeatedVals_t<EigenSizes, 4, 3>;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<my_type, EigenSizes<4, 4, 4>>);
```

### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EKidYwbKxoSHXgyQ)